# Loadsave module - Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using Rob Miracle's loadsave module for my Corona SDK game

I have this little Enquiry on it

If I save a json table on mydata.lua

```
M={}
M.highScore = 0
M.levels=1

loadsave.saveTable(M,"settings.json")

return M
```

Now if in the game.lua...I do this....

```
function gameOver
    If gamewin == false then
    mydata.level = mydata.level + 1

gamewin = true

loadsave.saveTable(mydata,"settings.json")

end
```

Now if I do this will the loadsave module overwrite the whole json file and hence remove the high score parameter from there?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. From [the source](http://omnigeek.robmiracle.com/2012/02/23/need-to-save-your-game-data-in-corona-sdk-check-out-this-little-bit-of-code/) of `saveTable` definition:

```
function saveTable(t, filename)
    local path = system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local file = io.open(path, "w")
    if file then
        local contents = json.encode(t)
        file:write( contents )
        io.close( file )
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

As you can see, the function uses `io.open(path, "w")` to write to file. Since, `io.open` creates an entirely new file when used with the write mode (`w` parameter), the older file would be overwritten.

You can instead load the contents from the json file first, before writing over with new values:

```
function gameOver()
    local mydata = loadsave.loadTable "settings.json"
    if gamewin == false then
        mydata.level = mydata.level + 1
        gamewin = true
    .
    .
    .
    loadsave.saveTable(mydata,"settings.json")
end
```

Comment: @user5331438 It'd still overwrite the file. But you won't lose the previous settings.