# Detecting the first app start (corona SDK)

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I am developing a game using Corona SDK. For some reason I need to detect the first time the app starts. I searched for tutorials regarding this topic but couldn't find any. I have no idea how I can detect the first ever session or startup of the game.

Can anybody help me out?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag and save/read from file, eg.

**1.** Use a flag that tracks if your app starts for the first time, eg.

```
    local firstRun = true
```

**2.** When the app starts, check if file with its' state exist.

**3a.** If no file exist yet (=app starts for the first time), change the state of your variable to:

```
    firstRun = false
```

and save it to file.

**3b.** If the file does exist, read the state of that variable, and check if it's 'false' (=app has started at least once before).

You can use JSON for saving data in a file. Nice tutorial by Rob Miracle [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/10/14/tutorial-saving-and-loading-lua-tables-with-json/).

**NOTE:** Technically, just the presence/or lack of a file could be used to detect if your app has started once or not, but you might want to keep other app state variables in this file too, so using a dedicated flag would be better, as you could then keep toggling it's value to test your app start detection detection etc...

Comment: Hi can you please give a complete example with the code. Thank you

Comment: Given the above logic, and what you already have here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552832/loadsave-module-corona-sdk you should be able to work it out on your own. If not, post the code you will create, as a new question, and explain what problem is. Just remember, there are many people ready to help on SO, but if you ask for code, without showing an effort that you already have done some research, not only will you probably not get any help, but your questions will be downvoted. Remember, post quality questions, and you'll get plenty of help (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)